# Как передать Юзера?

Tags: java, spring, bootstrap4, thymeleaf

У меня есть задание сделать нового юзера (использую Spring Boot) и сначала я сделал через ссылку на страницу создания нового юзера, через гет запрос, контроллер ловит и передает в Model аттрибутом нового пустого юзера, а в форме уже заполняются поля, с помощью Thymeleaf и передается на пост контроллер, но когда я подключил Bootstrap там нет никакой переадресации, а просто открывается вкладка без подгрузки (видимо тут JS) и я не пойму как передать пустого Юзера, ведь гет запроса нет, все динамически, никак не могу понять как это реализовать

Comment: Вам необходимо его сохранить в bd ?

Comment: Да я хочу его сохранить в бд

Answer (score 0):

Для примера

Страница регистрации

```
 <form  th:action="@{/registration}" method="post">


            <lebel>Логин:</lebel>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Логин" required />

            <div>
                <lebel>Пароль:</lebel>
               <input type="password"  name="password"  class="form-control"  placeholder="Пароль" required minlength="8"/>

            </div>

            <div>
                <lebel>Фамилия:</lebel>
                <input type="text" name="lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Фамилия" required/>

            </div>
            <div>
                <lebel>Имя:</lebel>
                 <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Имя" required />

            </div>
            <div>
                <lebel>Отчество:</lebel>
              <input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control" placeholder=" Отчество"/>

            </div>
            <div>
                <lebel>email:</lebel>
               <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email@.com" required/>

            </div><br>
            <div>
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="login" type="com"*/-->

                <input type="submit" th:href="${login}" value="Зарегистрироваться"class="btn btn-success btn-block"/>
            </div>

        </form>


    </div>
```

Ваш контроллер

```
  @PostMapping("/registration")
public String addUser(User user, Map<String, Object> model ){



    if (!userService.addUser(user)) {
        model.put("message", "User exists!");
        return "/registration";
    }



    return "redirect:/login";

}
```

И UserService

```
public boolean addUser(User user) {
    User userFromDb = userRepository.findAllByUsername(user.getUsername());

    if (userFromDb != null) {
        return false;
    }

    user.setActive(true);
    Set <Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
    roles.add(USER);
    user.setRoles(roles);
    user.setActivationCode(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    userRepository.save(user);


           

    }
    

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Но ведь ваш кад не сработает, т.к. данные просто не передадутся из html в контроллер, разве нет?

Comment: Все нормально работает, или Вы все правильно сделали. Покажите кваш код.